# Negative sign in Python Subseting operations

Tags: python, subset

I have the following array:

```
np.random.seed(12)

s = np.random.randn(5, 5)
```

What does the negative sign implies in sub setting operation? I.e

```
s[1:-1, :]
```

Does it simply means the removal of a row in this case?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: It means you make a view where the first and last rows are removed. Of course these are not really removed, but the view does not sees these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the following example (this is not a code, of course!)

```
arr = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = arr[-4] = 2
arr[2] = arr[-3] = 3
arr[3] = arr[-2] = 4
arr[4] = arr[-1] = 5
```

negative signs in arrays refers to indexes in backward (from last item to first, starting with -1 to `-(arr.__len__()+1)`

Answer (score 1):

No this does not mean removal, with:

```
s[1:-1, :]
```

You just use every row except the first and the last one so if you do this:

```
s=np.random.randn(5,5)
print(s[1:-1, :])
```

then you get an 2D array of randoms with 5 arrays of 5 randoms. And if you print it then you will get s[1 (what is the sec element)] - s[sec last element]. But S will still have 5 arrays.